# to ssh and scp in one script

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I perform ssh to remote server to run a backup script. Then scp it to local machine.

```
1. ssh root@Remoteserverip sh ~/folder/backupscript.sh
2. scp root@Remoteserverip:/backupfolder/file.tgz /localfolder/
```

Is there any way to script these two operations in one script?

Ps: couldn't find solution elsewhere.

Comment: The line numbers shouldn't be there in the script file. Outside of that, I'm not sure why that wouldn't work -- what happens when you try it?

Comment: no. that's just to number the lines. and  @Tomas suggestion worked. trying to improve it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Just put those commands in the script and thats it.

```
ssh root@Remoteserverip sh ~/folder/backupscript.sh
scp root@Remoteserverip:/backupfolder/file.tgz /localfolder/
```

Comment: done. But the bash script ask remote server password, for each command written in the scrip. 
What to do?

Comment: So either enter the password twice, or change the ssh/scp login to use login using authorized private key with an empty passphrase. This is a security weakness of course, if anyone reaches the private key he can do the same. Or, you may use `ssh-agent` and this way you only enter the password once in a shell session, and subsequent calls will use it so you may call scripts without entering the password.